# HighCharts: How to change style of bottom most x-axis grid line

Tags: highcharts

I am using Highcharts for one of my project. Everything is okay except I could not change line style('Solid','ShortDash','ShortDot','ShortDashDot','ShortDashDotDot','Dot','Dash','LongDash','DashDot','LongDashDot','LongDashDotDot') of bottom grid line in x axis as shown in the attached image.

[image: I am using Highcharts for one of my project. Everything is okay except I could not change style() of bottom grid line in x axis as shown in the attached image.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the line you highlighted is not a `gridLine` of `yAxis` and dash style does not apply to it. In fact it covers the bottom-most grid line. Disable it by setting its width to 0.

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.lineWidth
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.gridLineDashStyle

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/mnp6xa57/

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is easily achievable with CSS `nth-of-type` selector (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type). Example: http://jsfiddle.net/hfkz9ys1/.